# Adding an image to div moves surrounding divs

Tags: html, css

This should be simple but I just can't figure it out. I have 3 divs displayed as inline block. Whenever I put an svg image (or any image, for that matter - I linked a jpeg and got the same result but I need to have inline svg in this case) inside of one the divs, it causes the other two divs to move down.  What could be causing this? Why are the divs no longer on the same baseline?

[Resulting behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk9gX.png)

Here is my (simple) code, less the very lengthy svg bit:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Merch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="headingcontainer">
        <div class="div1">1</div>
        <div class="div2">
            <svg
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="div3">3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.div1, .div2, .div3 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.div1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.div3 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Someone please make me feel like an idiot by pointing out what's going on here. :-)

Comment: Please edit yur question and add more code (which is help to us to reproducible your problem) because your code not testable by a screenshot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can add - the code I submitted is everything but the very lengthy svg content. I could add that in but the problem occurs whether it's the svg file or another image in the div. The screenshot is simply to demonstrate the effect I am seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you add `vetical-align: top;` to the elements it will work. inline-block elements are `vertical-align: baseline;` unless otherwise specified.

Example:

```css
.div1,
.div2,
.div3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="headingcontainer">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>
```

Just a bit about the default `baseline`:

> Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent.
> The baseline of some replaced elements, like , is not
> specified by the HTML specification, meaning that their behavior with
> this keyword may vary between browsers.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! I thought it must be something as simple. Thank you so much for your quick and effective answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do that. It's done now. Thanks again for your help.